# Accessing Highmaps with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, highmaps

I'm building some interactive maps in Highmaps but I'm wondering how I can access the highmaps object through JQuery in a similar manner to [here](http://ahumbleopinion.com/highcharts-tips-accessing-chart-object-from-container-id/) ?

Comment: Please insert the code from the link to your post directly (but keeping the link in your post is ok, since one can find additional info there)

Comment: The idea of getting highmaps chart is similar to what you have found in the article you send us link to. If you will have any problems with getting this object, please post more specific information about your issue, the best would be jsFiddle showing the issue.